# Define small named packages in your node application without having to publish them to npm

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I'm wondering if there is a way with node to make a directory a containing package, like `__init__.py` does it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your package is in a directory named "node_modules", and that directory is locatable somewhere shallower in the filesystem tree that the requiring module, `require` will find it. So you could do:

```
myapp.js
node_modules/mylib/package.json
node_modules/mylib/index.js
```

and `myapp.js` could just `require("mylib")`. This also works if that `node_modules` directory is anywhere shallower in the fs.

That's the simple solution but it isn't commonly done because most people want to `.gitignore` their `node_modules` directory and only put transient third party stuff in there.

This problem is extensively and exhaustively discussed in the gist [better local require paths](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520). I recommend reading through that for other approaches. Ultimately I think things end up as totally separate projects packaged as separate modules, so move toward that end state as soon as it is justified.